# how do I select a specific column in a pivot_table - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to select a specific column from a table and store it as a data Frame and **not a series.**
that data frame needs to have country and directer id.

this is the contents of the table:

```
                                    country_id  director_id  duration     gross    
    country       director_name                             
    Argentina   Juan Jose Campanella    16          61         129.0    20167424.0      
    Australia   George Miller           19          39         120.0    153629485.0
```

Comment: Do you think `df[['director_id']]` ?

Comment: that returns a series. not a data frame

Comment: Hmm, are use sure? `print (type(df[['director_id']]))`